# Nice way to prove $\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^{\epsilon}-1}{\epsilon}=\ln(a)$

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I know how to prove the following limit

> $$\lim _{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^{\epsilon}-1}{\epsilon}=\ln(a)$$

But I am looking for a nice way to do it, a little elegant. Would you have one?

Comment: L'hoptial works nicely

Comment: Not elegant, but the limit is by definition the derivative of $a^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Hmm that's a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean like the answer ?

Comment: @Dibs: I don't know what you mean by like the answer, but $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$, and now finding the derivative (Chain Rule) is easy.

Comment: L'hopital is ridiculous, because if $f(x)=a^x$ then $f'(0)$ is defined as the limit in question. To prove $f'(0)=\ln a$ is just the same question. @user160738

Comment: Informally: If $e^x=\lim_{N\to\infty}(1+\frac xN)^N$, then "solving" for $x$ on the right gives $\lim_{N\to\infty}((e^x)^{1/N}-1)N=x$. Set $x=\ln(a)$ and $\epsilon=\frac1N$. Problem is, I'm not sure how to justify "solving" for $x$ like that.

Comment: What definition of $a^x$ are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way you can solve this only by using derivatives... and limits as well, here is how I would solve this problem.

First calculate the derivative $(y^x)'$, where the prime denotes derivation in respect to the variable x. This should give you $$(y^x)'=y^x \ln(y)$$ Then you find the limit as $x \rightarrow0$.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(y^x)'=\ln(y) \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} y^x=\ln(y)$$
Then you use the definition of the derivative to rewrite the left side of the equation.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^{x+\epsilon}-y^x}{\epsilon}=\ln(y)$$
$$\iff \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} y^x \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}=\ln(y)$$
$$\iff \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}=\ln(y)$$

Comment: That is indeed pretty nice. Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than using l'Hôpital's rule but then it is the traditional way to solve the problem.

Comment: No need to set $x\to 0$, just set $x=0$. Everything is continuous.

Comment: yeah I know but the point was to get rid of the limit anyways. But yes, indeed, you could not use the limit because it is continuous as Thomas Andrews said.

Comment: Alright I knew it anyway. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, without the use of derivatives:

$a^\epsilon = e^{ln(a^\epsilon)}$. The series expansion of $e^x$ is $\sum _{n =0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}$. Then we have $e^{ln(a^\epsilon)}= \sum _{n =0}^\infty \frac {(ln(a^\epsilon))^n}{n!}= 1 + \frac {ln(a^\epsilon)}1 + \frac {({ln(a^\epsilon)})^2}2 + ... + \frac {({ln(a^\epsilon)})^k}{k!}+...$

Thus our limit is now $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac {-1 + \sum _{n =0}^\infty \frac {ln(a^\epsilon)^n}{n!}}{\epsilon}$ = $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac {-1 + 1 + \frac {ln(a^\epsilon)}1 + \frac {({ln(a^\epsilon)})^2}2 + ... + \frac {({ln(a^\epsilon)})^k}{k!}+...}{\epsilon} $ $= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac {\epsilon ln(a) + \frac {{\epsilon}^2 {(ln(a))}^2}{2} + ... + \frac {{\epsilon}^k {(ln(a))}^k}{k!} + ...} {\epsilon}$ $=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} { ln(a) + \frac {{\epsilon} {(ln(a))}^2}{2} + ... + \frac {{\epsilon}^{k-1} {(ln(a))}^k}{k!} + ...} = ln(a)$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$${a^\epsilon-1\over\epsilon}=\ln(a){e^{\epsilon\ln(a)}-1\over\epsilon\ln(a)}=\ln(a){e^h-1\over h}\quad\text{where }h=\epsilon\ln(a)$$

Note that $\epsilon\to0\iff h\to0$.  Thus

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}{a^\epsilon-1\over\epsilon}=\ln(a)\lim_{h\to0}{e^h-1\over h}=\ln(a)$$

provided you know that ${d\over dx}e^x=e^x$.